# MVVM ViewModel inside ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm, data-binding

I'm trying to convert an existing Windows Form software to MVVM/WPF. I'm new to MVVM so I can make a lot of mistakes.

In that app, these are my main objects simplified:

The **Product** class, this class keep the info of every distinct product by the UPC. Also, there can be many products of the same UPC, but every physical item has a unique identifier, like UPC-date-serial, so this unique identifier is saves in a list inside the Product class.

```
class Product
{
    // This is the barcode of the product
    public UPC
    { get; set; }

    // This is a list which contains the unique ID of every product 
    public List<string> ProductSerialCodes
    { get; set; }

}
```

In that way, if we have 10 products of the same UPC, we have a single instance of the Product class with 10 items in the ProductSerialCodes list.

Then, the **Container** class, this class is to identify every physical box filled with products. A box can contain different products.

```
class Container
{
    // The box Id
    public string ContainerID
    { get; set; }

    // The list of products in the box
    public List<Product> ProductList
    { get; set; } 
}
```

These classes have more code, and self validated functions, so I think is better to make them ViewModels.

The ProductViewModel:

```
class ProductViewModel
{
    List<string> _productSerialCodes = new List<string>();

    public string UPC
    { get; set; }

    public List<string> ProductSerialCodes
    { get { return _productSerialCodes; } }

    public int ItemsCount
    { get { return _productSerialCodes.Count; } }

    public AddItem(string itemID)
    {
        _productSerialCodes.Add(itemID);
        OnPropertyChanged("ItemsCount");
    }
}
```

*Note: The AddItem() method is called from a background thread.

The ContainerViewModel:

```
public class ContainerViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<ProductViewModel> _productList;

    public ObservableCollection<ProductViewModel> ProductList
    { get { return _productList; } }

    public string ContainerID
    { get; set; }

    public AddItem(string itemID)
    {
        // This comes from a background thread.
        // I find the product related to the item,         
        // (If the product doesn't exist in the list I create it)
        _productList.Find(product).AddItem(itemId);
    }
}
```

So this is my approach to MVVM, my MainViewModel has a ContainerViewModel and on the screen I want to display the list of products, and quantities, example:

```
UPC          Qty
000000000000 12
```

As the data comes from a background thread, it must be updating by the INotifyPropertyChanged automatically.

Another thing I've noticed is, I need to click somewhere in the window for the UI to update. After reading a few blogs, I've found that using a SynchronizationContext object can solve that issue:

Then when OnPropertyChanged(propertyName) is called, I call this

```
SynchronizationContext _syncContext;
_syncContext.Post(delegate { CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested(); }, null);
```

but this only works when I'm making a test on the UI thread. In my new application, as the data comes from a background thread, SynchronizationContext  is null, so, this solution didn't work.

I've already read Josh Smith's [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) and karl shifflett's [Stuff](https://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2010/05/09/stuff-wpf-line-of-business-using-mvvm-video-tutorial/). These are great, btw.

So, The questions are:

-Is my approach correct? I'm open to new ideas.

-How can I bind a ListBox, or other control to a property in a ViewModel inside another ViewModel?

-How can I marshall the OnPropertyChanged to the UI thread, and the update is applied without the need to click on the window?

**--EDIT**

My main problem is displaying the data.

If my MainViewModel looks like this:

```
public class MainViewModel
{

    private ContainerViewModel _currentContainer = new ContainerViewModel();

    public ContainerViewModel CurrentContainer
    { get { return _currentContainer; } }

    // more code...
}
```

Then in the View, to display the ProductList, my xaml is:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>

<ListBox Grid.Column="0" Margin="5"
            ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentContainer.ProductList}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding UPC}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemsCount}" />
            </DockPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

- *NOTE: The data template will be different, however, what I want is to see the items in the listbox.*

When I run the application, in background, the ViewModels are being populated. If I set a breakpoint, I can see items in the observable lists.

But nothing on the screen, the ListBox remains empty

Thanks for your time.

Regards.

Comment: I wrote an article about mvvm best practices in wpf, maybe it is interesting fot you too: https://blog.rsuter.com/recommendations-best-practices-implementing-mvvm-xaml-net-applications/

Answer (score 0):

You can define `ProductSerialCodes` as ObservableCollection to bind the View.

```
public ObservableCollection<string> ProductSerialCodes
    { get { return _productSerialCodes; } }
```

Also, to update the ObservableCollection (as it is being updated in background thread instead of primary thread), you should use Dispatcher object.

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
            {
              <<Your code>>
            }));
```

Answer (score 0):

> -Is my approach correct? I'm open to new ideas.

If ProductList is not modified at runtime, I think it is better if you declare it as List and make ProductSerialCodes as ObservableCollection.

> -How can I bind a ListBox, or other control to a property in a ViewModel inside another ViewModel?

Usually, the Parent-Child (children as collection) type of ViewModels, are perfect to any ItemsControl derived controls such as ListBox. You just need to bind the ItemSource to the children and have a Template for the items. The child ViewModel will be bounded to the Item's view.

> -How can I marshall the OnPropertyChanged to the UI thread, and the update is applied without the need to click on the window?

I agree with user1672994, the Dispatcher can do it.

Comment: (1) ProductList can be modified at runtime, if needed, a new ProductViewModel can be created and added to the list. (2) I'm having problems to bind the Listbox to the Container.ProductList collection, I've added a xaml snippet. (3) I do agree with him. Thanks for your time.

Comment: There are no errors when the application runs. Or, are they thrown in an specific window? How can I see those errors? I'm using VS2015 Community. There's nothing on Inmediate Window, or Output when I run it.

Comment: Your code should work. The only thing left is making sure that the Window has Datacontext set. Either you snoop it or handle DataContextChanged to check it.

Comment: The datacontext was established in the xaml, I added that snippet in the xaml. Then, I've moved it to the code behind of the view, and nothing. Also, in the codebehind, I created a global MainViewModel instance, and them set it in the Initialize(), and, in the ListBox (which I placed a x:name in the xaml) set the datacontext to that global variable in the Loaded() event of the codebehind, Nothing happened.